# Deobfuscating self-encrypted Javascript - how to check what is being executed

Tags: javascript, encryption, self-reference

I'm trying to 'disassemble' javascript code that is sending spam to places. It is using `eval()` to run parts of the code from an obfuscated string.

My question is: what can I use to check what commands are actually running through the interpreter? Trying to undo evals "by hand" is quite tedious.

Here is the code I'm struggling with:

```
eval(function (p, a, c, k, e, d) {
    e = function (c) {
        return (c35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36));
    }
    while (c--) {
        if (k[c]) {
            p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
        }
    }
    return p;
}('//loooong encrypted part here//'.split(|)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like minitech said, `console.log("There is an error here")`.

You can check for the message by using the Javascript console. If you are on Google Chrome, `Menu -> Tools -> Javascript Console`. Or `Ctrl Shift J`.

The old, traditional method would be to use `alert("Error!")`. Not recommended, but you can use it if you find delight in immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `eval` with `console.log`. Repeat.